# Why is my Folding at Home client only using 25% of my CPU?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, folding-at-home

I have a new rig with an i5 2500k overclocked to 4.8GHz.

It doesn't have a GPU yet, so I'm going to let it do some Folding at Home. I installed the latest Folding at Home client, but in Task Manager, it only shows one process – and that process never exceeds 25%.

Why is it not using 100% of my CPU power? I have four cores available. I made sure that 'Do not lock cores to specific CPU' was ticked in the advanced configuration of the client.

Comment: Task manager shows it is using all 4 cores but overall the limit is 25%.

Comment: Just because a process is set to run on all cores (keyword affinity), doesn't mean it'll be able utilize all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Did you download the [SMP](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/DownloadWinOther) High Performance client? You are probably running the old uni-client which is only singlethreaded. You should use version 6.34 or even the version 7 beta client.

See [this](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/WinGuide) guide for a proper installation and use of the version 7 client. Start at "QuickStart" there is also the download link.

Comment: Just tried to install v6.41 but it won't let me run it as it says I have no gpu in my system. I cannot for the life of me see any link to a v7 beta.

Comment: @baobeithebaobei oops, my fault sry, it is the 6.34 for CPU. I will add a link to v7 download.